# How to say "Luke, I am your father" in Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, idiom

I have found very diverse translations online:

- [Luke, sum ipse patrem te](http://www.eudict.com/?lang=englat&word=Luke,%20I%20am%20your%20father.%20(Star%20Wars))
- [Luca, pater tuus sum](http://orig09.deviantart.net/51df/f/2016/053/7/8/luke__i_am_your_father___latin__by_legoguy87-d9sqk8a.png) (or in a [different order](https://youtu.be/7peadBMosmI?t=44s))
- [Luke, ego patrem tuum sum](http://noiamyourfather.org/)

**My guess**

First, the Latin name Luke seems to be [Lucas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas_(given_name)).

Second, I would say the vocative need to be used here. In this case, it is [Luca](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Lucas#Declension). The vocative of Pater is also pater.

Finally, ego sum tuum seems to be "I am your". Ego, however, seems to be used only for [emphasis](https://www.quora.com/When-in-Latin-would-you-use-the-word-ego-to-refer-to-yourself), and it is not necessary. Provided the context of this phrase however (dramatic scene in Star Wars), I would say that the correct translation is:

> Luca, pater ego sum tuum

I am not sure about the order though. Would the above be correct?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Give the context of the (mis)quote, I'd offer:

> Luca, *ego* pater tuus sum.

In Latin, "your" is most often the adjective *tuus*, and thus declines with the noun it modifies. Because *pater* is masculine, so too would be *tuus*. If it were 'mother', then you'd have *mater tua*.

The order *pater tuus* is assured, though *tuus pater* isn't impossible. There's no reason to separate it, though, like you did. You'd only really see that in poetry, and then it's done for some purpose (either meaning or, more likely, meter).

The emphasis can change depending on what you include. I think having *ego* is appropriate, but different speakers will use different things and they're not necessarily wrong.

Finally, for the actual quote, this would be a great example of using [*immo*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=immo&la=la#lexicon). Note that Darth Vader actually says, "No, *I* am your father." In Latin, this could be rendered:

> Immo ego pater tuus sum.

The *immo* here counters what was previously said ("He told me you killed him") and points to a correction of it.

The *sum* is optional, since *ego* is already spelled out, though I'm torn as to whether Vader would drop it. There's something to be said about the rhythms of a snappy sentence (without the *sum*) v. the fuller, more formal sentence (with it).

Comment: No comma after immo?

Comment: @luchonacho Commas are modern, so I don't really pay attention to them. Some editors would put a comma there, some might not.

Comment: Wouldn't the Latin form of **Luke** be **Lucius**?

Comment: I agree that *Immo ego pater tuus (sum)* is very fitting. It matches the nuance and rhythm of Dad Vader's line well. @TheHonRose I believe Luke comes from Lucas, which in turn comes from Lucius.

Comment: @TheHonRose It's been established since at least the Vulgate that Lucas is the translation of Λουκας, from which we get the name Luke.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Etymonline derives it otherwise: `Luke, from Latin Lucas (Greek Loukas), contraction of Lucanus literally "of Lucania."`

Comment: You need the "sum" (=am) but the "ego" = "I" is optional; you get that from the verb form.  Without the "sum" there's no verb, so you get "No, I  ??? your father", which is an incomplete sentence.

Comment: @JerryTheC Incomplete sentences in both English and Latin are permissible if the verb is understood from context. For a Latin example, see Plautus *Truculentus* 5.957: `Immo ego vero, qui dedi.`

Answer (score 12):

Here's a quick transcript of the preceding lines:

> Luke: I'll never join you.
>   Vader: If you only knew the power of the dark side. Obi Wan never told you what happened to your father.
>   L: He told me enough. He told me you killed him
>   V: No, I am your father

I like C.M. Weimer's suggestion: here is a slight modification that does not require any vocal inflection to understand exactly what the *immo* is referring to. I will use Plautus as my pattern:

> Bal. Quid est ei homini nomen?
>   Sim. Leno Ballio.
>   Bal. Scivin ego? **Ipse ego is sum**, adulescens, quem tu quaeris. (Plautus, *Pseudolus* 975-77)

Here is the dialogue in context:

> Lucas: Numquam tecum consociabo.
>   Vader: Si modo vim cognosceres partis obscurae. Obi Wan numquam tibi dixit quid patri tuo evenisset.
>   L: Sat mihi dixit. Mihi dixit te eum occidisse.
>   V: **Immo, ipse ego pater tuus sum.**
>   L: Eheu! Eheu! Eheu!

Comment: Love the *eheu*s!

Comment: Both answers were great, but I feel oblige to accept the first one. It would be great to be able to accept two answers!